# Sending email with data from form

Tags: php, html, forms, contact-form

I have problem with simple contact box. I want to send informations from form to my email.

Already tried with register globals on and off (.httacess), tried with simple $formname and $_POST['formname'] but still getting email without form info.

```
<?php

        if ($action == "send"){//isset wyslij




    //if (!$name || !$email || !$phone || !$enquiry) {
        //$problem = TRUE;
       //echo("<p>You have to fill all form.</p>");
    //}     

    if (!$problem){


    $name = $_POST['name'];    
    $data = date("d.m.y");


    $message = "
    <p>Name: $name</p>
    <p>Phone: $phone</p>
    <p>Email: $email</p>
    <br>
    <p>Enquiry: $enquiry</p>";


$od = "blabla@email.com";
$content = $message;
$header = "From: $od \r\n";
$header  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
     (mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'New message from website Angelzena', $content, $header));



                     echo("<br><p>Message has been sent.</p>");

    }else{
          echo("<p>Try <a href=contact.php>again</a></p>");
         }                    
}


?>



        <form action="contact.php?action=send" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        <label  for="name">Name</label><input type="text" name="name" /></br></br>
        <label  for="email">Email</label><input type="text" name="email" /></br></br>
        <label  for="phone">Phone</label><input type="text" name="phone" /></br></br>
        <label  for="enquiry">Enquiry</label><textarea name="enquiry" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea></br></br>
        <input type="submit" id="contact_button" value="Send" />
        </form>
```

Comment: your script isnt getting any of the input fields except `name`, unless you left out part of your script.

Comment: _forget about register_globals_! You should absolutely not be using it. Access your form values via `$_POST['email']`

Comment: i tried like this $name = $_POST['name'];, but i didnt get name value in email so this is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

`<form action="contact.php?action=send" method="post" enctype="text/plain">`

When POSTing forms the `enctype` attribute should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

PHP does not handle forms POSTed as `text/plain`.

Comment: Well spotted.  Since there's no file component, the `enctype` should just be omitted.